# I would like to know what this says. Thanks in advance

Tags: meaning, character-identification

[image]

Trying to find put what this seal means.

Comment: turn it clockwise 90 degree, “x家xx”?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Is this your seal? It'd be be better if you chop it on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0):

i mean, turn the picture 90 ° clockwise, then “flip” it horizontally, we would have:

[image]

the bottom right character is “家”

the top right character might be (my best guess) “人”

so, the verse would be “xx人家”, or, “人家xx”

Comment: Do you know how i can find out its meaning?

Comment: Thankyou.  I am still unsure what it says bit trying to find out. Its a hand carved Shanshou buddha seal.  Probably soapstone.  Just wanted to find out what it said to get a better idea of how old it may be. Thankyou for replying.